# Mouse clicked event non-responsive in java

Tags: java

I am trying to write a test java program in order to learn how mouse listeners work in java. Basically, I was trying to write a graphics program and that if I click on the canvas, the program generates a label "hello" at the place where I clicked my mouse. But nothing happens after I click my mouse. Here is my code. Can anybody help me with it?

```
import acm.program.*;
import acm.graphics.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class test extends GraphicsProgram{
    public void run(){
        addMouseListeners();
    }
    public void MouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
        label=new GLabel("Hello",e.getX(),e.getY());
        add(label);
    }
    private GLabel label=null;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `MouseClicked` be `mouseClicked`.  Try adding `@Override` before the method to see if you are actually overriding any method that might be called by the parent class...

Comment: Thanks. That's so stupid of me!